# $\mathbb{P}(\tau_a\leq \tau_{-a}\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(\tau_{3a}\leq t)$ for a Brownian motion?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $\tau_a$ denote the first passage time to $a>0$ for a Brownian motion $W(t)$. Then is the claimed identity true?

$$
\mathbb{P}(\tau_a\leq \tau_{-a}\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(\tau_{3a}\leq t)
$$

I had a heuristic (diagram) idea through reflection principle, but I am not sure if it is correct. The form of reflection principle that I am using is,
$$
\mathbb{P}(\tau_a\leq t, W(t)\leq b)=\mathbb{P}(W(t)\geq 2a-b)
$$
where $b\leq a$. I am not able to rigorously prove or disprove the identity above since I am not able to deal with the joint distribution of the first passage time with the reflection principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claimed identity is not true. Rather than trying to use an identity derived from the reflection principle, it is better to use the reflection principle directly.
Let $\gamma_{-a}:=\min\{t>\tau_a: W_t=-a\}$. Then applying  reflection  at time $\tau_a$ shows that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\tau_a\leq \gamma_{-a}\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(\tau_{3a}\leq t) \,. \tag{1}
$$

However, applying reflection  at time $\tau_a$ also shows that

$$
\mathbb{P}(\tau_a\leq \tau_{-a}\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(\tau_a\leq \tau_{-a} \quad \text{and} \quad \tau_{3a}\leq t) \,. \tag{2}
$$
Incidentally,  we can obtain a lower bound for the difference between (1) and (2) by applying the Markov property at time $\tau_a$:

$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_{3a}\leq t)-\mathbb{P}(\tau_a\leq \tau_{-a} \quad \text{and} \quad \tau_{3a}\leq t) =$$ $$ =\mathbb{P}(\tau_a>\tau_{-a} \quad \text{and} \quad \tau_{3a}\leq t) \ge $$  $$ \ge \mathbb{P}(t/2 \ge \tau_a> \tau_{-a} \quad \text{and} \quad \tau_{3a}\leq \tau_a+t/2) =$$ $$ =
\mathbb{P}(t/2 \ge \tau_a> \tau_{-a})  \cdot \mathbb{P}(\tau_{2a}  \le t/2) \ge $$ $$\ge \mathbb{P}( \tau_{-3a} \le t/2)  \cdot \mathbb{P}(\tau_{2a}  \le t/2)\,.$$
(using reflection at time $\tau_{-a}$ in the last step.)

Comment: Thank you Prof. Peres!